# Manual rollback of an application / service

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric application with a few services underneath it. They are all currently sitting at version 1.0.0.

I deploy an update out to the cluster for version 2.0.0. Everything is running fine and the deployment succeeds. I notice a very large but in the version. Is there a way to manually rollback to version 1.0.0? The only thing I have found is automatic rollback during an upgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matt's answer is correct, but I'll elaborate a bit on it here.

The key is in understanding the different steps during application deployment:

- [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125905.aspx)
- [Register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125958.aspx)
- [Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125913.aspx)
- [Upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125975.aspx)

Visual Studio rolls these up into single "publish" and "upgrade" operations to make it easy and convenient. But these are actually individual commands in the Service Fabric management API (through PowerShell, C# or HTTP). Let's take a quick look at what these steps are:

**Copy**:
This just takes your compiled application package and copies it up to the cluster. No big deal.

**Register**: 
This is the important step in your case. Register basically tells the cluster that it can now create instances of your application. Most importantly, you can register multiple versions of the same application. At this point, your applications aren't running yet.

**Create**:
This is where instances of your registered applications are created and start running.

Before we get to upgrade, let's look at what's on your cluster. The first time you go through this deployment process with version 1.0.0 of your application (call it FooType), you'll have just that one type registered:

`FooType 1.0.0`

Now you're ready to upgrade. You first **copy** your new application package with a new version (2.0.0) up to the cluster. Then, you **register** the new version of your application. Now you have two versions of that type registered:

`FooType 1.0.0`

`FooType 2.0.0`

Then when you run the **upgrade** command, Service Fabric takes your instance of 1.0.0 and upgrades it to 2.0.0. If you need to roll it back once the upgrade is complete, you simply use the same **upgrade** command to "upgrade" the application instance from 2.0.0 back to 1.0.0. You can do this because 1.0.0 is still registered in the cluster. Note that the version numbers are in fact not meaningful to Service Fabric other than that they are different strings. I can use "orange" and "banana" as my version strings if I want.

So the key here is that when you do a "publish" from Visual Studio to upgrade your application, it's doing all of these steps: it's copying, registering, and upgrading. In your case, you don't actually want to re-register 1.0.0 because it's already registered on the cluster. You just want to issue the **upgrade** command again.

For an even *longer* explanation, see: [Blue/Green Deployments with Azure ServiceFabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872863/blue-green-deployments-with-azure-servicefabric/35881220#35881220)

Comment: So does Service Fabric keep "copies" of the application packages as long as a version is registered?

Comment: Also, make sure you copy your application parameters when doing an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the same upgrade procedure, but targeting your 1.0.0 version instead.  "Rollback" is just an "upgrade" to your older version.

Comment: Fails with 'An attempt to upgrade the application but the application's version has not been changed. Be sure to update the version in the application manifest prior to upgrading.' I did update it...back to 1.0.0. In fact I did a git checkout on the version tag.

Comment: You'll see that error if the ApplicationTypeVersion value in your local app manifest matches the ApplicationTypeVersion of the app that exists in the cluster.  Verify both the versions and the application names between the local project and cluster.  Using Service Fabric Explorer is handy tool to verify what's defined on the cluster.

Comment: I'm' not sure I follow. I have my application type WebreferenceApplicationType that shows version 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 in the explorer. The running application is version 1.0.1. What are you saying the steps are to publish 1.0.0 again? Because the publish fails when I try and do 1.0.0 (e.g. rollback or upgrade to my older version)

Comment: Not sure why this error is occurring then.  You may be able to bypass this check by adding DisableAutoDiffPackaging="true" as an attribute on the root element of the publish profile you are using to publish.

Comment: Did you update only the ApplicationType version, or the sub elements versions as well (like the service, code package)?

Comment: @itaysk I rolled back all of the versions. 1.0.0 across the board.