# Upgrade/downgrade service fabric application with already deployed version

Tags: azure, deployment, upgrade, azure-service-fabric

In Service Fabric cluster, If application has multiple versions(say 1.0.0,1.0.1,1.0.2), then how can we shift the application to one version to another version(say active is  1.0.0, then I wanted to shift to 1.0.1) with out redeploying the application. Is there a PowerShell command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the PowerShell command

```
Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade
```

This being said I did hit an issue with my local cluster, telling me I couldn't upgrade / roll back the application if the service description had changed, which it hadn't. Using an Azure hosted cluster this worked as expected, perhaps an inconsistency with how the package is copied into the image store.

Depending on what you are attempting to achieve you could also look at named instance where you are able to deploy multiple versions of an application at once, for A - B testing.

Here are some similar posts:

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193477/manual-rollback-of-an-application-service/37313448)
[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872863/blue-green-deployments-with-azure-servicefabric/35881220#35881220)

EDIT:

Thanks to Aleksey L for the comment below. With a bit of messing around due to types not being the same and as long as you haven't changed any parameters between versions this will work,if you have you will need to manually build up the hash table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For fixing _service description had changed_ "error" you should provide `-ApplicationParameter<Hashtable>`. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929302/upgrade-service-fabric-application-powershell)