# Staging slot and vip-swap

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Coming from the classic Cloud Service model, after having used it to 5 years now, we are very used to the concept of a staging slot and the vip-swap capability. Yes this upgrade model has many warts but also many benefits.

Clearly the SF doesn't expose this model. So I wonder was it just not a popular model in Cloud Services, or does it just really not make sense 6 years later?

Is this one of those paradigm changes where I just have to re-think how we deploy, and forge ahead with the newly prescribed model (rolling upgrades)? Or are there known techniques to setting up something like staging slots with SF?

Looking for advice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VIP swaps don't make sense for stateful compute, and Service Fabric is largely a stateful compute platform (even if you only use stateless services, the system services themselves are stateful). If your services have your data in them, you have to do a rolling upgrade if you want to keep your data and keep it consistent.

So yeah, it's a paradigm change, but a good one. It encourages continuous delivery and frequent upgrades because upgrades are integrated right into the platform and don't cost you anything extra. You don't need to pay for staging VMs, which can get expensive for large deployments, and that might even discourage continuous delivery.

Now, you can do something similar to a staging deployment for stateless services. In Service Fabric, your "deployments" are applications, not VMs. So you can create an instance of a new application version side-by-side with an instance of the previous application version and route your traffic however you want, whether that's gradually move users to the instance of the new version, or just flip a switch and send all your traffic to the new version all at once. This of course doesn't work for stateful services, because all of your data is still in the previous version application instance.

Comment: Excellent food for thought Vaclav. My gut says to make the paradigm shift, but it's good to know I do have options.

Comment: @Vaclav is this "similar to a staging deployment" process documented somewhere?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872863/blue-green-deployments-with-azure-servicefabric/35881220#35881220