# Service Fabric - A/B Testing for Stateless Service

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

We are planning to host our Stateless Web APIs in Azure Service Fabric. We want to create service upgrade strategy in accordance with A/B testing. I have created an Application with version 1.0.0. Once I deploy this application in a Service Fabric Cluster, I would make changes in my application and upgrade it to version 2.0.0.

Is it possible to have a side by side deployment of same service with different versions in a service fabric cluster and then direct customers to each of these versions based on customer identifier? We would like to do A/B Testing for new version before migrating all customers to new version of the service.

What will be the public URL for external clients in this case for consumption of these WebAPIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a side by side deployment of same service with different versions in a service fabric

Yes.

> and then direct customers to each of these versions based on customer identifier?

Yes.

> What will be the public URL for external clients in this case for consumption of these WebAPIs

If you have only one cluster with the same nodes, then it will be the same. You can have another cluster for this purpose.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872863/blue-green-deployments-with-azure-servicefabric) answer as there some details and discussion on possible obstacles with migrating of users' data.