# Service Fabric Multiple Environments and Versions Side-By-Side

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Looking at Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm) that says, under "Multiple deployment environments (production and staging)", that the "Service Fabric allows you to have multiple environments for your apps or to deploy different versions of your app side-by-side."  How is this done and what does the topology look like?  At any point in the cycle would different VMs in the cluster be at different versions or would different versions be installed on the same VMs? Particularly interested in Dev/Test/Prod environments, not simply upgrading Prod through a staging mechanism, though that would be good to better understand as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Different versions can run on the same VM, provided they don't claim the same ports. Did you see the answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872863/blue-green-deployments-with-azure-servicefabric

Comment: Any code samples that demonstrate registering app names / versions and deploying instances  of app names to run on specified ports?  Should I use parameters for port numbers in ApplicationManifest.xml and parameter values in files under ApplicationParameters (e.g., Cloud.xml)?  What's a good exampe of xml files (including those under PublishProfiles) to support Dev/Test/Prod side by side?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-specify-port-number-using-parameters

Comment: That's how you use parameters for port numbers, but does not say how to set it up for environments.  From the default Visual Studio template I have Cloud.xml, Local.1Node.xml, and Local.5Node.xml.  Obviously I could set a different port number value for a port number parameter in each of these files.  For environments, should I rename these files to Dev.xml, Test.xml, Prod.xml (prepending Local if the cluster is local)?  The Local Cluster manager lets me "Switch Cluster Mode" - I can only have one mode, either "1 Node" or "5 Node".  What do I do for environments?  How do I manage versions?

Comment: Found an article up my alley - anyone try this?: [Continuous Deployment of Service Fabric Apps using VSTS (or TFS)](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/continuous-deployment-of-service-fabric-apps-using-vsts-or-tfs)